# Why Deferred Lighting ruins FPS? (2D)

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, hlsl, deferred

Why Deferred Lighting ruins FPS?
I tried to put about 20-26 deferred lighting on the viewable space of my Map, and it brings down the fps from 61 to 28-31.

It also makes my VGA temperature to go from 68°C to 72-73°C.
I feel this a bit weird, because it's just 2D.
And I don't think It should be this much calculation to halve my FPS.

So basically I don't understand why this method costs so much.
Or is there a problem with my code and how I try to solve it?

Also is there any other method for good lighting,which costs much less then this?
Point Lights?

My code is:

```
 Texture_Lights = RenderTargetBase.GetTexture();
 for (int i = 0; i < LightRef.Count; i++)
            {


                //Draw lights
                for (int techniqueindex = 0; techniqueindex < LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Techniques.Count; techniqueindex++)
                {
                    LightRef[i].Parent.effect.CurrentTechnique = LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Techniques[techniqueindex];

                    LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters["time"].SetValue(((float)timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds) * 0.0000158f);
                    LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters["GameTime"].SetValue(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
                    LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters["lightPosition"].SetValue(
                        new Vector3(
                            (LightRef[i].Position.X-CameraX)/(1.0f/ZoomFloat), 
                            (LightRef[i].Position.Y-CameraY)/(1.0f/ZoomFloat),
                            0
                            ));


                   LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters["screenWidth"].SetValue(this.Width);
                   LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters["screenHeight"].SetValue(this.Height);



                    for (int cx = 0; cx < LightRef[i].Parent.SelfTextures.Count; cx++)
                    {
                        LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Parameters[LightRef[i].Parent.SelfTextures[cx]].SetValue(RenderTargetBase.GetTexture());
                    }




                    foreach (EffectPass pass in LightRef[i].Parent.effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                    {


                        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, RenderTargetLights);
                        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearColor);

                        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);
                        LightRef[i].Parent.effect.Begin();
                        LightRef[i].Parent.effect.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
                        pass.Begin();

                        spriteBatch.Draw(
                         Texture_Lights,
                         new Vector2(0,0),
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, Texture_Lights.Width, Texture_Lights.Height),
                        Color.White,
                        0,
                        new Vector2(0, 0),
                        1.0f,
                        SpriteEffects.None,
                        0);

                        spriteBatch.End();
                        pass.End();
                        LightRef[i].Parent.effect.End();

                        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null);
                        GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearColor);

                        Texture_Lights = RenderTargetLights.GetTexture();
                    }




                }






            }




            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null);
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearColor);

            //Draw the Lightings #2
            if (Texture_Lights != null)
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend, SpriteSortMode.Immediate, SaveStateMode.None);

                spriteBatch.Draw(
                 Texture_Lights,
                 new Vector2(0, 0),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, Texture_Lights.Width, Texture_Lights.Height),
                Color.White,
                0,
                new Vector2(0, 0),
                this.ZoomFloat,
                SpriteEffects.None,
                0);

                spriteBatch.End();
            }
```

And Shader:

```
float GameTime;
float time;

texture2D colortexture;
texture2D normaltexture;

float ambient = 1.00;
float4 ambientColor = (1, 1, 1, 1);

float3 lightPosition = (230,230,0);
float4 lightColor = (120,120,120,120);
float lightPower = 0.27;

float screenWidth = 1000;
float screenHeight = 600;

sampler ColorMap = sampler_state
{
 Texture = <colortexture>;
};

sampler NormalMap = sampler_state
{
 Texture = <normaltexture>;
};



float4 DeferredNormalPS(float2 texCoords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{
 float4 base = tex2D(ColorMap, texCoords);
 float3 normal = tex2D(NormalMap, texCoords);

 float3 pixelPosition = float3(screenWidth * texCoords.x, screenHeight * texCoords.y,0);

 float3 direction = lightPosition - pixelPosition;
 float distance = 1 / length(lightPosition - pixelPosition) * lightPower;
 float amount = max(dot(base + normal, normalize(distance)), 0);
 lightColor *= lightPower;

 float4 finalColor = (base * ambientColor * ambient) +
 (base * distance * amount * lightColor * ambient);

finalColor.a = base.a;

 return finalColor;
}


technique Deferred
{
 pass Pass1
 {
 PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 DeferredNormalPS();
 }
}
```

Comment: You should try asking at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . They are much more knowledgable about graphics rendering.